# How to connect github repo with aws using cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, pipeline, aws-cdk

Im learning aws cdk and trying to make a code pipeline.

i created personal access key on github and saved it on aws secret manager.

then in my cdk stack i wrote`

```
pipeline.addStage({
      stageName:"Source",
      actions:[
        new CodePipelineAction.GitHubSourceAction({
          actionName: 'CheckOut',
          owner: 'Mahmood787',
          repo: "aws-pipeline",
          oauthToken: cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager('github2'),
          output:sourceOutput,
          branch:"master" 
        })
      ]
    });
```

on cdk deploy im getting this error

> Webhook could not be registered with GitHub. Error cause: Invalid credentials [StatusCode: 401, Body: {"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}]

is there anything im missing?

Comment: I am using the same approach (oauthToken, SecretsManager and GitHub repository). Could you please check if your token works with the GitHub RESt API using e.g. curl.?

Comment: yea it was token issue

Comment: Also do check in the github repo for branch name, As you tend to provide "master" branch but Gtihub uses "main" branch.

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [401 Bad credentials when try to hook code pipeline with GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905312/401-bad-credentials-when-try-to-hook-code-pipeline-with-github)