# 401 Bad credentials when try to hook code pipeline with GitHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I got this error message when try to do `cdk deploy PipelineStack`:

```
Webhook could not be registered with GitHub. Error cause: Invalid credentials [StatusCode: 401, 
Body: {"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}] 
(Service: AWSCodePipeline; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; 
Request ID: dbab7e3e-ed28-42b8-a2d5-7539be32776b; Proxy: null)
```

Why am I seeing above error?

I even tried verify the token stored in AWS secret manager directly

```
curl -H "Authorization: token token-stored-in-secretManager" https://api.github.com/users/my-user
```

and it return `200` response.

My issue is similar to [How to connect github repo with aws using cdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65467320/how-to-connect-github-repo-with-aws-using-cdk)

BTW, my github repository is set as private not public. Not sure if that matters.

#### Context

Here is my CDK code for the source stage.

```js
  pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "Source",
      actions: [
        new codepipeline_actions.GitHubSourceAction({
          actionName: "Checkout",
          owner: "the-owner",
          repo: "the-repo",
          branch: "main",
          oauthToken: CDK.SecretValue.secretsManager(
            "website-GitHubToken"
          ),
          output: outputSources,
          trigger: codepipeline_actions.GitHubTrigger.WEBHOOK,
        }),
      ],
```

And this is my personal access token permissions:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's my fault.

I did not store the token properly:
[image]

It should be stored like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you secret in AWS Secrets Manager is stored as a key/value pair, you'll have to use `SecretsManagerSecretOptions` with `CDK.SecretValue.secretsManager`. Below is an example, and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_core.SecretsManagerSecretOptions.html) is the `SecretsManagerSecretOptions` documentation.

```js
pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "Source",
      actions: [
        new codepipeline_actions.GitHubSourceAction({
          actionName: "Checkout",
          owner: "the-owner",
          repo: "the-repo",
          branch: "main",
          oauthToken: CDK.SecretValue.secretsManager(
            "Secret name", { jsonField: "key" }
          ),
          output: outputSources,
          trigger: codepipeline_actions.GitHubTrigger.WEBHOOK,
        }),
      ],
      ...
})
```